# How get reactive form value component in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

How to access the value of each of the iterated forms of the child component ?.
The parent component has a button which must generate an array of child forms, but must go through all those forms.
Can it be with a viewChid?

**HTML**

```
<form novalidate
  [formGroup]="fatherForm">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items>
      <children-form
        [item]="item">
      </children-form>
    </div>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
<button (click)="save()">Save</button>
```

Comment: Can you explain bit more with code of `childern-form` component

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `@ViewChildren`, here is a demo.

```
@ViewChildren(ChildrenFromComponent)
childrenFormCmps: QueryList<ChildrenFromComponent>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.dir(this.childrenFormCmps);
}
```